# Error when executing "googlesamples-assistant-pushtotalk"

Tags: google-assistant-sdk

I've error on executing below command:

```
"googlesamples-assistant-pushtotalk --project-id my-dev-project --device-model-id my-model"
```

That gives me error as:

```
File "/home/pi/env/bin/googlesamples-assistant-pushtotalk", line 6, in <module>
    from googlesamples.assistant.grpc.pushtotalk import main
File "/home/pi/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/googlesamples/assistant/grpc/pushtotalk.py", line 28, in <module>
    import grpc
File "/home/pi/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/grpc/__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
    from grpc._cython import cygrpc as _cygrpc
ImportError: /home/pi/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/grpc/_cython/cygrpc.cpython-37m-arm-linux-gnueabihf.so: undefined symbol: __atomic_exchange_8
```

Comment: Where are you running this?

Comment: See relevant github issue for more updates: https://github.com/grpc/grpc/issues/20400

Answer (score 1):

Run this code in env:

`pip3 install 'grpcio==1.23.0' --force-reinstall`